# Katz and Lindell, proof of lemma 2.4

Tags: perfect-secrecy

Can someone explain the logic behind the claim that *the second equality is because we condition on the event that $M$ is equal to $m$* in the proof of Lemma 2.4 from "Introduction to Modern Cryptography"? I have added the relevant fragment below.

> **LEMMA 2.4** An encryption scheme (Gen, Enc,Dec) with message space
> $\mathcal M$ is perfectly secret if and only if Equation (2.1) holds for every $m,m_0 \in M$ and every $c \in \mathcal C$.

> **PROOF** We show that if the stated condition holds, then the scheme
> is perfectly secret; the converse implication is left to Exercise 2.4. Fix a
> distribution over $\mathcal M$, a message $m$, and a ciphertext $c$ for which $\mathrm{Pr}[C = c]$ > 0.

> If $\mathrm{Pr}[M = m] = 0$ then we trivially have $$\mathrm{Pr}[M = m | C = c] = 0 = \mathrm{Pr}[M = m].$$
> So, assume $\mathrm{Pr}[M = m] > 0$. Notice first that $$\mathrm{Pr}[C = c | M = m] = \mathrm{Pr}[\mathrm{Enc}_K(M) = c | M = m] = \mathrm{Pr}[\mathrm{Enc}_K(m) = c],$$
> where the first equality is by definition of the random variable $C$, *and the
> second is because we condition on the event that $M$ is equal to $m$*.

I'm having a hard time understanding how this follows from (or is connected to) the definition of conditional probability $$\mathrm{Pr}[\mathrm{Enc}_K(M) = c | M = m] = \frac{\mathrm{Pr}[(\mathrm{Enc}_K(M) = c)\wedge(M=m)]}{\mathrm{Pr}[M=m]}.$$

Answer (score 2):

*Intuitively*, the reasoning behind their statement is that given your random variable $M$ equals $m$, then $\mathrm{Enc}_K(M)$ becomes $\mathrm{Enc}_K(m)$.

To see this formally consider the statement $\mathrm{Pr}[(\mathrm{Enc}_K(M) = c)\wedge(M=m)]$ from your numerator. Note that $M$ refers to the *same* random experiment on both sides. We may rewrite the statement as $\mathrm{Pr}[K=k \land M=m : \mathrm{Enc}_k(m) = c]$ which makes the random choices more explicit.
As, by assumption, the choices of random variables $K$ and $M$ are independent, this equals $\mathrm{Pr}[K=k: \mathrm{Enc}_k(m) = c]\cdot \mathrm{Pr}[M=m]$. Writing the first factor more concise again this is just $\mathrm{Pr}[\mathrm{Enc}_K(m) = c]\cdot \mathrm{Pr}[M=m]$.
Plugging this into your fraction leads, as desired, to $$\mathrm{Pr}[\mathrm{Enc}_K(M) = c | M = m] = \frac{\mathrm{Pr}[(\mathrm{Enc}_K(M) = c)\wedge(M=m)]}{\mathrm{Pr}[M=m]} = \frac{\mathrm{Pr}[(\mathrm{Enc}_K(m) = c)]\cdot \mathrm{Pr}[M=m]}{\mathrm{Pr}[M=m]}=\mathrm{Pr}[\mathrm{Enc}_K(m) = c]$$